# Using is_page_template inside loop

Tags: loop, templates

I have tried this:

```
<?php 

$query = new WP_Query(
 array(
  'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
  'post_parent' => $parent_id
 )
);

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
                                                                                       
if (is_page_template('my-template.php')) {
    echo 'is my template';
 } 
                                               
endwhile;

?>
```

My template is in the theme's root and so is the template where I am placing the code.

Comment: What are you actually trying to check? The custom template used by the current post in the loop?

Comment: Yes that's right, I want to loop through posts but only those using a certain template.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the required result like this:

```
<?php
  $template = get_page_template_slug();

  if ($template === 'my-template.php') { 
   //do stuff
  }
?>
```